# Autosynthesized property 'delegate' will use synthesized instance variable '_delegate', not existing instance variable 'delegate'

Tags: objective-c

I'm following the guide [here](http://www.hardcodedstudios.com/home/ryan-newsome/simpledelegatetutorialforiosdevelopment) to create a custom delegate. It runs fine but I get the following warning in xcode

> DetailViewController.m:23:1: Autosynthesized property 'delegate' will
>   use synthesized instance variable '_delegate', not existing instance
>   variable 'delegate'

Can anyone advise how to get rid of the warning

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The most idiomatic way to handle this situation is simply to remove your `delegate` ivar declaration.  If you were using your `delegate` ivar, you should use the implicit ivar `_delegate` instead.

**Why does this work?**

As of [Xcode 4.4 (LLVM Compiler 4.0)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/ObjCAvailabilityIndex/), instance variables and accessor methods are synthesized automatically for a property *if the `@synthesize` directive is not used explicitly for that property*.  As [Apple's documentation on encapsulation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) states

> By default, [...] accessor methods are synthesized automatically for you by the compiler, so you don’t need to do anything other than declare the property using @property in the class interface.

The ivar that is used for a property (which is gotten and set by the automatically synthesized property accessor methods) is named `_<propertyName>` (i.e. the ivar's name is the property's name prefixed with an underscore).

In this case the property name is `delegate`, so the the ivar that is used is `_delegate`.  This is already happening in your code.  When you call `-delegate` and `-setDelegate:`, this ivar `_delegate` will be gotten and set.

However, you've also declared your own ivar `delegate`.  Of course, the ivar you explicitly declared (`delegate`) will not be gotten and set by the instance methods `-delegate` and `-setDelegate:` since the automatically synthesized ivar (`_delegate`) is being gotten and set.  However, (almost always--if it wasn't, your code is ambiguous) your intent was for your ivar `delegate` to be the thing that your property's accessors would get and set.  Luckily, the compiler is clever enough to notice what you've done, and that's why it is emitting this warning:

> warning: autosynthesized property '`delegate`' will use synthesized instance variable '`_delegate`', not existing instance variable '`delegate`' [`-Wobjc-autosynthesis-property-ivar-name-match`]

It's telling you that your property `delegate` will use the automatically synthesized ivar `_delegate` rather than the ivar that you explicitly declared, `delegate`.

So if you simply delete your `delegate` ivar, the compiler will stop emitting this warning.  If you were using the `delegate` ivar directly (not through the property), start using `_delegate` instead.

---

A minor variation on this option is to explicitly declare the same ivar (`_delegate`) that the automatic synthesis of the `delegate` property is creating.  You can do this by replacing

```
@interface TheClass : TheSuperclass
{
    //...
    id<TheDelegateProtocol> delegate
    //...
}
@end
```

with

```
@interface TheClass : TheSuperclass
{
    //...
    id<TheDelegateProtocol> _delegate
    //...
}
@end
```

This works because automatic synthesis of a property will always use an ivar whose name is the property's name prefixed with an underscore.  If no such ivar exists, the ivar will be generated.  If it does exist, it will be used.

---

If instead you would prefer that your property's accessors set and get your ivar `delegate` you can add an `@synthesize` directive to your class' `@implementation` to tell the compiler to do just this:

```
@implementation TheClass
//...
@synthesize delegate = delegate;
//...
@end
```

The line `@synthesize delegate = delegate;` tells the compiler to use the ivar `delegate` (the right hand of the assignment) in the accessors for the property `delegate` (the left hand side of the assignment).

You can also omit the right hand side of the `@synthesize` assignment and just write

```
@implementation TheClass
//...
@synthesize delegate;
//...
@end
```

This works because a property with a manual `@synthesize` which does not explicitly specify the ivar to be gotten and set by its accessors (such as `@synthesize delegate;`) will use an ivar with the same name as the property, NOT prefixed by an underscore.  This has to do with backwards compatibility.

Comment: I'm used to not having to synthesize properties in xcode anymore. Could you explain why I have to take this approach with delegate properties and not other types of properties / instance variables?

Comment: You have explicitly created a variable named `delegate`. LLVM (or something) is smart enough to notice that you have a property named `delegate` (which auto-synthesizes a variable named `_delegate`) and a variable named `delegate`, which is likely an error. It's betting that you intended that variable to be a backing variable for the property, but made a typo somewhere.

Comment: Another option would be to just delete the instance variable, and let the compiler create it automatically for you. Unless you're doing something special, you shouldn't need to declare it yourself.

Comment: if I delete the 'delegate property I get the following error. `Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'DetailViewController *'; did you mean to access ivar 'theDelegate'?`

Comment: As I wrote in my answer "You will still be able to access the ivar backing the property, but, as with the first option, it will still be `_delegate`, not `delegate`.".  You need to replace every use of the ivar `delegate` with a use of the name autogenerated ivar `_delegate`.  What is your ivar `theDelegate`?

Comment: theDelegate is a typo, sorry. I ended up deleting `id<TheDelegateProtocol> delegate` and now it works. I presume there will be no side effects?

Comment: The only "side-effect" is that the ivar backing your `delegate` property will be `_delegate` rather than `delegate`.

Answer (score 2):

There's another method and this one worked for me:

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) id <MyDelegate> delegate;
```

You can then add this to the implementation without error:

```
@synthesize delegate;
```

Also: This is ARC compliant.