# How to fix warning Autosynthesized property 'view' will use synthesized instance variable '_view', not existing instance variable 'view'

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uiviewcontroller, nsviewcontroller

I get the following warning/error in xcode:

```
Autosynthesized property 'view' will use synthesized instance variable '_view', not existing instance variable 'view'
```

when I was trying to redefine/override the class of the `view` property on my NSViewController.

```
@interface DABListViewController : NSViewController
  @property (nonatomic, strong) DABListViewControllerView *view;
@end
```

Also, the view doesn't seem to appear.  This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505995/how-to-fix-the-warning-of-autosynthesized-property-myvar-will-use-synthesized) looks similar but didn't work.

Comment: `NSViewController` already has a property called `view`.  You can't override that property by declaring another property with the same name. What you can do is 1) create an instance of `DABListViewController` 2) alloc/init a `DABListViewControllerView` as a local variable 3) call the view controller's `setView:` method to change the view.  Either that, or just use the Identity inspector in Interface Builder to change the class of the view.

Comment: I see thanks. Can this comment be an answer? I don't feel like my question is a duplicate of either of the questions it's marked a duplicate of.  This comment answers my question but conflicts the [answer I found here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16423616/1252895) as far as I can tell.

Comment: After a question gets closed, it's not possible to add answers. That's why I posted as a comment. FWIW, I agree that your question is not a duplicate of the ones they chose.

Answer (score -3):

Including the `@dynamic view;` in my implementation file fixed the problem.

```
@implementation TSPollListViewController

  @dynamic view;

  - (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[DABListViewControllerView alloc] init];
  }

@end
```

The `@dynamic` tells the compiler not worry about the properties because they'll be taken care of at run time.  I guess in telling the compiler to ignore the property we don't override the `view` instance variable defined in `NSViewController`.  I think this also means there is no `_view`.  This should work with `UIViewController` and most properties you want to redefine the `Type` for in subclasses.

Comment: @dynamic isn't the correct solution... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505995/how-to-fix-the-warning-of-autosynthesized-property-myvar-will-use-synthesized/19506189#19506189

Comment: To re-emphasize;  **DO NOT DO THIS!**  Totally the wrong "fix";  not a fix at all.

Comment: Hmm, sorry @bbum. So this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16423616/1252895) is also wrong and misleading or is there a different situation there? I thought I was essentially doing what was described there, but when I left out the `@dynamic` I got the warning.

Comment: [Travis Jeffery in his blog](http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/12/overriding-uiviewcontrollers-view-property-done-right/) has highlighted exactly this solution as absolutely correct. Can anyone explain where is the truth?

Comment: @waggles It doesn't fix anything, it just silences the warning for unrelated reasons.  You'll still end up with two instance variables -- `view` and `_view` -- and much confusion will ensue the first time you use the wrong one.

Comment: @bbum; As far as I know about @dynamic, it just prevents autogeneration of accessory methods, so the subclass will use superclass's setView: and view methods, so everything there should be fine, or not?

Comment: @NAlexN Derp (Wow. derpity-derp, in fact). Yes, correct.  Thanks.  Fixed: Travis's weblog post doesn't actually explain why he used `@dynamic`.  It relies on passing through to super;   it also relies on co-variant declarations, which is explicitly verboten in Objective-C, but is coincidentally safe in this case.