# id <SampleProtocolDelegate> delegate vs id <SampleProtocolDelegate> _delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, delegates, protocols

I'm new to protocol delegates and I am trying to understand the difference between the 2 notations below.

In my protocol delegate file, I have defined

```
@interface SampleProtocol : NSObject
{
    id <SampleProtocolDelegate> delegate;
}
```

which gives me a warning, so I changed this piece of code to

```
@interface SampleProtocol : NSObject
{
    id <SampleProtocolDelegate> _delegate;
}
```

and it works as I had intended it to. So I would like to know why the syntax is **id  _delegate** whereas most tutorials I have seen is just **id  delegate** in the protocol definition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184691/autosynthesized-property-delegate-will-use-synthesized-instance-variable-del/14184752#14184752

Comment: Did you create a property for delegate as well, or only the ivar?

Comment: Which warning do you get?

Comment: You most likely want the instance variable to be `__weak`, as you have most likely defined the property.

Answer (score 2):

You have a property named `delegate` also, but have not included an explicit `@synthesize`. Implicit synthesize creates a backing instance variable with the name `_propertyName`. If you create an instance property with the name `propertyName`, the compiler is kind enough to warn you that there will be two instance variables.

If you have a property, you don't have to create the instance variable yourself. The compiler will create one for you. Leaves your code cleaner.

Comment: Thanks! this is definitely helpful!

Comment: "If you have a property, you don't have to create the instance variable yourself." It's not the same. Synthesized or auto-synthesized instance variables are `@private`. Instance variables declared in `@interface` are by default `@protected`.

Comment: @newacct True, but it also depends on the place of definition. For instance, a protected instance variable defined in a class extension in the .m file would not be useful, unless a subclass is defined in the same file. In the example above, it would technically matter, yes. But for **most** intents and purposes, the `@private`, `@protected` and `@public` notation is archaic and not used these days.

Answer (score 0):

You always want to name ivars with a leading underscore. If you create properties, the compiler will automatically create the underscore ivar for you. To illustrate:

This code:

```
// header
@interface MyGreatClass : NSObject
@property NSInteger someNumber;
@end

// implementation
@implementation MyGreatClass
@end
```

Is the same as this:

```
// header
@interface MyGreatClass : NSObject {
    NSInteger _someNumber;
}

- (void)setSomeNumber:(NSInteger)someNumber;
- (NSInteger)someNumber;
@end

// implementation
@implementation MyGreatClass
- (void)setSomeNumber:(NSInteger)someNumber
{
    _someNumber = someNumber;
}

- (NSInteger)someNumber
{
    return _someNumber
}
@end
```

No need for the `@synthesize` keyword.

One more thing: Unless you are creating a class that represents something like a network protocol, be aware that a protocol is similar to an interface in Java: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! I will start using property from now on!